# Debugging/tracing embedded sql

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, trace, embedded-database

Is there a way to trace/log sql from the code (not from the db side, but rather what the code thinks it's doing)?

I am using Pro*C/C++: Release 8.1.7.0.0 for Oracle

Answer (score 1):

"the code thinks it's doing"
Code doesn't think. If it did, I wonder if we would have more or fewer problems :)

But you could look into [SQLNet trace](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14212/troublestng.htm#sthref1729) at the SUPPORT level if you are interested in what statements the client is sending to the server (and responses back) rather than the statements executed by the server (ie omitting SQL executed by a procedure on the server rather than directly issued by the client).

Comment: My code thinks - based on what I tell it to do, though sometimes it  seems to misunderstands me...